# Как повторить программу

Tags: pascal

Здравствуйте!

Задача такая: как после вывода нужной информации спросить: "Повторить еще раз? ". Если пользователь отвечает Y, то повторить, в обратном случае ввести любой другой символ.

Условие: Ввести число от 0 до 5. Вывести его название на английском.

```
program Easy;
var num: integer;
begin
 write('Введите число от 0 до 5 ');
 readln(num);
 if (num>5) or (num<0) then
 writeln('Неверно указан номер');
 case num of
 0:write('Zero');
 1:write('One');
 2:write('Two');
 3:write('Three');
 4:write('Four');
 5:write('Five');
 end;
 end.
```

Comment: Изучайте:

* [Типизированные константы Pascal-Паскаль](http://www.pascal.helpov.net/index/pascal_Typed-constants)
* [Программирование. Циклы Pascal-Паскаль](http://www.pascal.helpov.net/index/cycles_pascal_programming#pascal-cycles_4)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте while вместо if. Точнее, Until.

Так же можно упростить

```
if num=1 then write('One');
```

заменив на

```
write(numbers_array[num]);
```

где

```
numbers_array - array of string
```

Например, так: 
Можно еще красивее, но лень.

```
program Easy2;
var num: integer;
begin
 write('Введите число от 0 до 5 ');
    repeat
 readln(num);
 if (num>5) or (num<0) then begin
  writeln('Неверно указан номер');
 end;
until (num<5) and (num>0);
 case num of
  0:write('Zero');
  1:write('One');
  2:write('Two');
  3:write('Three');
  4:write('Four');
  5:write('Five');
 end;
end.
```

Comment: А как тогда повторить программу, чтоб после вывода названия числа на английском можно было вводить числа дальше?

Comment: И еще, можно ли 6-9 строчку обьединить в две?

Comment: что за 6-9?

Comment: А как тогда повторить программу// написать еще один while или repeat-until. 
Вокруг всего. Только придумайте условие выхода, иначе будет крутиться до бесконечности.